# Meteor events only binding to first element

Tags: javascript, meteor, event-handling, dom-events

I am struggling to understand how Meteor adds event bindings to templates.

I have a template with multiple anchors for the navigation dropdowns:

```
<template name="user_loggedin">
  <li  class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a profile..
    <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">List</ul>
  </li>

  <li  class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
      <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"> </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

And I try to bind a click event to show the dropdown menus:

```
Template.user_loggedin.events({
  "click a.dropdown-toggle": function(e,tml) {
  $(e.target).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggle()
  }
})
```

However, the event only seems to bind to the **first anchor element**, not all of those matching the 'a.dropdown-toggle' selector.

The same problem occurs for templates containing dynamic elements derived from collections.  I'd just assumed the Meteor template events method would work in the same way as `$('a.dropdown.menu').on(...`

I suspect this is to do with Meteor not having rendered all the template's DOM elements before the events are bound.  I've seen solutions using Meteor.*template*.rendered to bind events after rendering, but this seems messy considering Meteor are deprecating rendered method in the next release.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

No. The event handler is specified for the template and is not "bound" to an element. So your event handler will definitely be executed if any anchor element with class `dropdown-toggle` is clicked.

The problem you are experiencing is probably caused by the use of `e.target` instead of `e.currentTarget` in your event handler. From the Meteor docs:

> **target**
>
> The element that originated the event.
>
> **currentTarget**
>
> The element currently handling the event.
>   This is the element that matched the selector in the event map. For
>   events that bubble, it may be target or an ancestor of target, and its
>   value changes as the event bubbles.

In the first case both `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` are `a.dropdown-toggle` and everything works as expected. In the second case, however, `e.target` is `i.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog` while `e.currentTarget` is `a.dropdown-toggle` (which is what you want to have).

So please try to edit your event handler to look like this:

```
Template.user_loggedin.events({
  "click a.dropdown-toggle": function(e,tml) {
      $(e.currentTarget).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggle()
  }
});
```

About your second problem with the dynamic elements: can you provide an example?